# Can't figure out where to put template ID in mailjet API call

Tags: php, mailjet

I am sending a campaign using the mailjet API. My function to do that currently looks like this:

```
public function sendCampaign($listName, $config, $vars) {
    //First we need to set up a draft of the campaign.
    $listId = $this->config['lists'][$listName];
    $title = $config['subject'] . "_" . time();
    $requestBodyOne = [
        'Locale' => 'de_DE',
        'Sender' => $config['fromName'],
        'SenderEmail' => $config['fromEmail'],
        'Subject' => $config['subject'],
        'ContactsListID' => $listId,
        'TemplateID' => $config['template'],                                //TODO: Figure out how to get templating to work -- right now, this is being ignored!
        'Title' => $title,
    ];
    $responseOne = $this->client->post(Resources::$Campaigndraft, ['body' => $requestBodyOne]);

    if(!$responseOne->success()) {
        $responseOne->getStatus();
    }

    $data = $responseOne->getData();
    $draftId = $data[0]['ID'];

    //Now we add our body to the draft
    $requestBodyTwo = [
        'Html-part' => $vars['body'],
    ];
    $responseTwo = $this->client->post(Resources::$CampaigndraftDetailcontent, ['id' => $draftId, 'body' => $requestBodyTwo]);
    if(!$responseTwo->success()) {
        $responseTwo->getStatus();
    }

    //Now we can send the campaign
    $responseThree = $this->client->post(Resources::$CampaigndraftSend, [
        'id' => $draftId,
        'TemplateID' => $config['template']                                 //TODO: Figure out how to get templating to work -- right now, this is being ignored!
    ]);

    die(dump($responseThree));
}
```

(I realize that there are some smells in here -- I will break this into smaller functions once I get the big one working.)

Though I am setting the TemplateID in two places, I can't seem to get mailjet to use the template (which takes in a single "body" variable). Instead, my message gets sent as HTML with no wrapping template. I have verified that my template exists.

What am I probably doing wrong here?

====

Edit: Changing hte request so it looks like this:

```
    $requestBodyTwo = [
        'Vars' => ['body' => $vars['body']]
    ];
```

... results in 400 error: "Properties not supported in JSON payload"

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting for possible template errors? https://dev.mailjet.com/template-language/sendapi/#templates-error-management

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just turned on template error reporting, and it looks like no errors are present.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the loop on this: We ended up using the /send endpoint and feeding in a value for MJ-campaign. That did the trick.

https://dev.mailjet.com/reference/email/send-emails/

Comment: Beware that send api does not use exclusion list, and also you will probably need to handle unsubscriptions by yourself.